# JS variable inside JSON string from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am generating a JSON string from a PHP array to echo a JS object.
This is what I want to get in js:

```
var myVar = 123;    
//php output:  
var obj = {a:1, b:[1,2], c: myVar, d:Date.UTC(2014, 0, 07)}
```

This is what I have:

```
<?php  
$array = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>array(1,2), 'c'=>???, 'd'=>???);  
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

The question is: What I put in PHP instead of question marks so that it won't be converted to string?

Comment: _so that it won't be converted to string_? What type of variable is it? If you do `json_encode` it will always be parsed as a string I think.

Comment: FYI: That is not JSON. JSON does not have variables in it and it does not call methods.

Comment: JSON should be uncoupled from your application. You shouldn't be placing variable pointers inside of it... It's a data store, not a collection of variables.

Comment: You can't do this (at least not with `jsoon_encode()`. Have a look at [json.org](http://json.org/) definition for values. You could just code your own encoder, but that would not be according to the standard.

Comment: I just thought json would be the best way to conver PHP array to JS object

Comment: JSON is a notation, not an object. What you have in JS above is a JS object.

Comment: @lvil It is the best way, but JSON != JS Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually do something like that:

```
<?php  
  $array = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>array(1,2),
    'c'=>'@#myVar#@',
    'd'=>'@#Date.UTC(2014, 0, 07)#@'
  );
  $json = json_encode($array);
  echo preg_replace('/\"\@\#(.*?)\#\@\"/', '${1}', $json);
?>
```

But in js `JSON.parse` won't work, so:

```
eval("var x = " + json_from_php);
```

Not such a good idea, but if you need it, it'll work. Just remember not to use this with any "json" which are generated not by your server.

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't support variables or special Date objects. You can only use scalar values (strings, numbers, booleans), arrays and objects (associative arrays).

A way to get what you want would be to return a .js file and have the browser execute that (by including it as a script) instead of transferring simple JSON data. Otherwise you could only define "special" strings that are handled by the receiving side. (For example, array `["var", "myVar"]` could be parsed accordingly.)

Comment: There is a commonly accepted date format for use with JSON, but it's type is still just a string.